# Android Synchronize API?

Tags: android, synchronization, icloud

On my samsung galaxy I navigate to "Settings>Wireless and network> Synchronize" and I find options to create profiles and set the sync server,but I never came across any API which would let me create a sync server or let my application specify the contents I can sync.

Is it something that provides the functionality what iCloud provides to iPhones?

Please let me know if there are any tutorials that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the SampleSyncAdapter code under the SDK samples. It will be in a directory akin to;

```
C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/samples/android-10/SampleSyncAdapter/
```

Link to original SO answer by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11518981/1348379)

Comment: Also, check out the other chaps [link](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html) on the original SO answer: